# get line from text and put into a linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I recently started coding in C and am following the excellent projects from [OSTEP](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/). One of the tasks is to reverse lines in a text file so that:

this / is / a /line

becomes

line / a / is /this

I settled on putting each line on a node in a linked list and then reversing this list. My question is why when i call `print_list` the result is empty? **After some debugging, it looks like the `head` node is not being set to `current` at the beginning**.

Also, if you have general comments on my code I would appreciate it so i can learn. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    char *line; 
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

void print_list(node_t *node) {
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", node->line);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file\n");
    }

    node_t *head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->line = NULL;
    head->next = NULL;

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t linecap = 0;
    ssize_t linelen;
    node_t *current = head;
    while ((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, fp)) > 0) {
        current->line = line;
        current->next = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = NULL;
    print_list(head);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"I settled on putting each line on a node in a linked list and then reversing this list"* - how is that going to reverse the content of a line like in the example you show? Seems like you would want one linked list per line and then one *word* per node of the linked list.

Comment: That's one way. I just wanted a line per node for the purpose of the exercise

Comment: OT: always check `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered by the user before ever accessing beyond `argv[0]`

Comment: regarding: `if (fp == NULL) { printf("cannot open file\n"); }` 1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.   2) when the error indication is from a C library function, also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` is made for this. Suggest: `perror( "fopen failed" );`  Note: this is a unrecoverable error.  When this error occurs, do not continue to execute the program as if the call to `fopen()` were successful.  Instead call: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: ``node_t *current = head;
    while ((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, fp)) > 0) {
        current->line = line;
        current->next = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_node_t *current = head;
    while ((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, fp)) > 0) {
        current->line = line;
        current->next = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        current = current->next;
    }t));
        current = current->next;
    }`  1) in C, do not cast the returned value from `malloc()`  cont:

Comment: cont: 2) `current->line = line;` only copies a pointer, not the actual text of the line. This is because a 'bare' reference to an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  Suggest: `strcpy( current->line, line );` however, since the struct only contains a pointer for `line` suggest: `current->line = strdup( line );`  3) please use paper and pencil to diagram what this code block is actually doing.

Comment: Please do not modify your posted code.  Such an action makes prior comments meaningless.  Rather, insert an EDIT section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You allocated a buffer and left its member `line` uninitialized. This will cause *undefined behavior* when it is used in `print_list`.
- You should set the pointer to `NULL` and the size to 0 to have [`getline()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) allocate buffer. Currently the buffer for first input is reused.
- `printf_list(head)l` should be `print_list(head);`.

Try this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("cannot open file\n");
    }

    node_t *head = NULL;

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t linecap = 0;
    ssize_t linelen;
    /* use pointer to node_t* for allocation */
    node_t **current = &head;
    while ((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, fp)) > 0) {
        /* allocate buffer only if some data is read */
        *current = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        if (*current == NULL) return 1;
        (*current)->line = line;
        (*current)->next = NULL;
        current = &(*current)->next;
        /* reset the parameter */
        line = NULL;
        linecap = 0;
    }
    print_list(head);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful. For `node_t **current = &head;` you're creating a pointer that points to the memory location of head? Also is it generally a good practice to initialize pointers to null when not immediately used? Thanks!